# Android app dies when a socket gets opened,

Tags: java, android, sockets

Please help. When i try to open a socket my android app dies. In android studio my logcat is empty (as well as in a separate logcat app on the phone). Permission added the socket is in a separate thread. Targeted sdk is 16 (this is an old phone). The app starts but crashes when i click on the button.
Please note: I am not a programmer just a hobbist and this is an arduino project. I havent deald with android since a 1-2 years (somewhere around api lvl 16 :) ) So my guess is i have something wrong with the back compatibilty of my knowledge. :)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public class Communication implements Runnable
{
    String ip, msg;
    int port;
    Socket socket;
    PrintWriter out;
    Context context;

    public Communication(String ip, int port, String message, Context context)
    {
        this.ip=ip;
        this.port = port;
        msg = message;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

                try {
                    socket =new Socket(ip, port);
                    out = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream());
                    out.println(msg);
                    out.close();
                    socket.close();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Message sent. Connection closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button lightOn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.lightOn);
    lightOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Thread(new Communication("192.168.1.160", 80, "light=on", context)).start();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Remove the Toast()s from your thread. Toasts()s cannot be used in threads. Replace by log statements.

Comment: It worked. sorry for stupid question.